# what is $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD']

Tags: php

I'm reading through the explanations of REST api [here](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) and there is the following code block there:

```
$this->method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($this->method == 'POST' && array_key_exists('HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD', $_SERVER)) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
        $this->method = 'DELETE';
    } else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $this->method = 'PUT';
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected Header");
    }
}
```

My question is what is `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD']`? I've googled around and the only thing I've found is the usage of `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header to transfer desired method of execution through `POST` method. Actually the code above seems like it's doing exactly it. So is it?

Comment: Is it what? This code is indeed doing what you describe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From Microsoft's article on `X-HTTP-Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541471.aspx):

> the X-HTTP-Method header can be added to a POST request that signals that the server MUST process the request not as a POST, but as if the HTTP verb specified as the value of the header was used as the method on the HTTP request's request line, as specified in [RFC2616] section 5.1. This technique is often referred to as "verb tunneling".

Short answer, the real HTTP verb that is in the header will be `POST` but applications will look for this special header to figure out what type of request was actually meant by emulating the HTTP verb.

Then, it's under `$_SERVER[]` because it's being sent as an HTTP header. Most HTTP headers are accessible under the `$_SERVER` array, and are prefixed with `HTTP_`.